# Django deployment. Error loading MySQLdb module. Trouble reading/writing from /tmp directory

Tags: python, django, apache, mysql

I'm deploying my Django app to another host/server using mod_wsgi and MySQLdb. Right now, I'm getting a 500 error with the following log:

ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: /tmp/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.4-linux-i686.egg-tmp/_mysql.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted

Did some research and it looks like the /tmp directory is non-exacutable. Found this: http://bit.ly/ckoIep

Can anyone shed some light on this, and possibly recommend a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point the [`WSGIPythonEggs`](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonEggs) directive to a writable, executable path.

Comment: Simple and easy solution Ignacio. Thanks.

Comment: Or python-eggs option if using WSGIDaemonProcess and daemon mode. On non Windows systems, unless you know about configuring Apache properly, it is recommended you use daemon mode.