# Error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted - Django runserver

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pip

I'm currently trying to launch my new django site on a remote server I've bought. I'm using python 2.7, Django 1.4.2 and MySQL as Database. I also use virtualenv and pip to make sure my environment matches these requirements.

After setting up the environment and syncing my db, I run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

But I get this output in the terminal:

```
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.4.2, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Anyone have any experience with this problem?

Help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: It might be related to this: http://bb10.com/python-django-user/2010-03/msg00783.html or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425715/django-deployment-error-loading-mysqldb-module-trouble-reading-writing-from-t

Comment: Seems you don't have permission to get port `8080`